# How to return a DataSet to a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am sending a standard Sql select statement to my Sql box via the SqlDataAdapter, then populating a DataSet object.

I can access the rows in the resulting DataSet, but how can I convert the DataSet into a List which can be returned to the MVC View. i.e. I'm assuming a List object is the best way to handle this.

Here's my controller c# code:

```
public class QAController : Controller
{

    private readonly static string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegrDBConnection"].ToString();
    private readonly static SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    private readonly static SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DbRegressionExec();
        return View();
    }
    public static void DbRegressionExec()
    {
        // SELECT TABLE CONTENTS FROM SQL !!
        RegressDB_TableList regresDB = new RegressDB_TableList();
        string sqlStr = "select * from [RegressionResults].[dbo].[Diff_MasterList] order by TableName";

        // POPULATE DATASET OBJECT
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, sqlConn);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlConn.Open();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds, "RegresDB");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }

       // I can iterate thru rows here, but HOW DO CONVERT TO A LIST OBJECT ????

        int numRows = ds.Tables["RegresDB"].Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            string tblName = ds.Tables["RegresDB"].Rows[i].Field<string>("TableName");
        }

        //List<RegressDB_TableList> masterList = regresDB.RegresTableList.ToList(); //not working !!
        //var masterList = regresDB.TableName.ToList(); //

    }

}
```

and a simple class I may need to make this happen:

```
namespace RegressionMvc.Models
{
  public class RegresDB_TableName
  {
     public string TableName { get; set; }
  }
  public class RegressDB_TableList
  {
     public List<RegresDB_TableName> RegresTableList { get; set; }
  }
```

}

In the end, I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle DataSet results from Sql Server and how to make them back to an MVC View.

I can probably go with jQuery and Json, meaning just convert the data fields to Json and return to JQuery, but I'm sure there are several ways to handle Sql based result sets.

Thanks in advance for your advice....

Best,
Bob

Comment: A model passed to a View can have a DataSet as a property (I'm pretty sure).  Is there a reason you're using DataSet and/or DAO instead of a more mature and strongly typed technology like Entity Framework or NHibernate (etc)?

Comment: What are you going to do with the dataset data in the view? If you need to edit it and return it to a a controller action, you may want to transfer the dataset data to a more view-friendly data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Directly answering your question:

```
var tableList = new List<RegresDB_TableName>();
int numRows = ds.Tables["RegresDB"].Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    string tblName = ds.Tables["RegresDB"].Rows[i].Field<string>("TableName");
    tableList.Add(new RegresDB_TableName() { TableName = tblName };
}

return View(tableList);
```

**Long answer** (that's actually shorter)

Try out [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

Your code could change to something like:

```
string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [RegressionResults].[dbo].[Diff_MasterList] ORDER BY TableName";
return sqlConn.Query<RegresDB_TableName>(sqlStr);
```

Comment: thank you everybody. i will try this stuff on Monday and post back asap. - Bob

Comment: Hi all - I'm not using EF nor NHibernate because I'm just writing a small front-end admin page to manage a DB Comparison tool I've written in Sql Server t-Sql. In this case I need to select from a couple of "master" tables as well as some of the Sql System Views. So it's not your typical application with CRUD requirements. Thank you all again !!!

Comment: @bob How does EF or NHibernate related to my answer?

Answer (score 5):

In your controller put the code like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult View(Modelclass viewmodel)
{
    List<Modelclass> employees = new List<Modelclass>();
    DataSet ds = viewmodel.GetAllAuthors();
    var empList = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Modelclass{
       AuthorId = dataRow.Field<int>("AuthorId"),
        Fname = dataRow.Field<string>("FName"),
       Lname = dataRow.Field<string>("Lname")
    });
    var list = empList.ToList();



    return View(list);
}
```

And in view

```
@{
var gd = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    gd.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
@gd.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table",

        columns: gd.Columns(
                 gd.Column("AuthorId", "AuthorId"),
                 gd.Column("Fname", " Fname"),
                 gd.Column("Lname", "Lname", style: "description")

 ))
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I don't see where the `List<Modelclass> employees = new List<Modelclass>();` statement ever gets utilized.

Answer (score 4):

If you're stuck with using DAO, I would suggest not using a DataSet and instead use a strongly typed class with the speed of [SqlDataReader.GetValues()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues.aspx) method.  It's more work, but it has to be done somewhere if you want strongly typed classes which I would highly recommend.

```
public class Person
{
  public Person(Object[] values]
  {
    this.FirstName = (string)values[0];
    this.LastName = (string)values[1];
    this.Birthday = (DateTime)values[2];
    this.HasFavoriteColor = (bool)values[3];
  }

  public string FirstName { get; private set; }
  public string LastName { get; private set; }
  public DateTime Birthday { get; private set; }
  public bool HasFavoriteColor { get; private set; }
}

public static void DbRegressionExec()
{
    List<Person> viewModel = new List<Person>();

    // SELECT TABLE CONTENTS FROM SQL !!
    RegressDB_TableList regresDB = new RegressDB_TableList();
    string sqlStr = "select
        FirstName
        ,LastName
        ,Birthday
        ,HasFavoriteColor
      from [RegressionResults].[dbo].[Diff_MasterList] 
      order by TableName";

    // POPULATE VIEWMODEL OBJECT
    sqlConn.Open();

    try
    {
      using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, sqlConn))
      {
        using (SqlDbReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
          while(reader.Read())
          {
            viewModel.Add(new Person(com.GetValues()));
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConn.Close();
    }

    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that @erik-philips. I've used SqlDbReader in the past, however in this case I'm just not sure what the best practice is. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Best practice in this case is a religious question.  Use DAO, Dataset, EF, NHibernate, they all work.  In my experience I use Entity Framework for all my projects (even small projects) that use any number of tables (even 1).  In my opinion the smaller the project the easier Entity Framework is to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Controller code

```
 //pQ is your query you have created 
 //P4DAL is the key name for connection string 

  DataSet ds = pQ.Execute(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Platform4"].ConnectionString);


  //ds will be used below
  //create your own view model according to what you want in your view 
 //VMData is my view model

 var _buildList = new List<VMData>();
            {
                foreach (DataRow _row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    _buildList.Add(new VMData
                    {  
     //chose what you want from the dataset results and assign it your view model fields 

                        clientID = Convert.ToInt16(_row[1]),
                        ClientName = _row[3].ToString(),
                        clientPhone = _row[4].ToString(),
                        bcName = _row[8].ToString(),
                        cityName = _row[5].ToString(),
                        provName = _row[6].ToString(),
                    });



                }

            }

  //you will use this in your view
  ViewData["MyData"] = _buildList;
```

View

```
@if (ViewData["MyData"] != null)
{

    var data = (List<VMData>)ViewData["MyData"];
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="display table"  id="Results">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Telephone</td>
                    <td>Category </td>
                    <td>City </td>
                    <td>Province </td>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in data)
                {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.ClientName, "_Display", new { id = item.clientID }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
                <td>@item.clientPhone</td>
                <td>@item.bcName</td>
                <td>@item.cityName</td>
                <td>@item.provName</td>

            </tr>

            }
            </tbody>


        </table>
        </div>
        }
```