# MVC4 put user information to usermodel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

This is `userModel`

```
public class userModel
    {
        public string userNo{ get; set; }
        public string userCode{ get; set; }     
        public string userName{ get; set; }     
        public string authtime{ get; set; }     
        public string duplLoginYn{ get; set; }  
        public string userLang{ get; set; }     
        public string siteLogo{ get; set; }     
        public string theme{ get; set; }        
        public string deptNo{ get; set; }       
        public string deptName{ get; set; }     
        public string usiteNo{ get; set; }
        public int connDur{ get; set; }      
        public string menuPosition{ get; set; } 
    }
```

and this is login controller

```
public ActionResult login(string id, string pass, string scode)
        {            
            Dictionary<string, object> sessionData = null;
            userModel userInfo = new userModel();

            String SqlCommand = "USP_LOGIN";
            OleDbParameter[] arParms = new OleDbParameter[3];
            arParms[0] = new OleDbParameter("ID", id);
            arParms[1] = new OleDbParameter("PW", pass);
            arParms[2] = new OleDbParameter("SCODE", scode);
            try
            {
                DataSet UserInfo = dataController.ExecuteDataset(dataController.CONN_STRING, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SqlCommand, arParms);
                if (UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //sessionData = new Dictionary<string, object>();                    
                    for (int i = 0; UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0].Table.Columns.Count > i; i++)
                    {
                        sessionData.Add(UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0].Table.Columns[i].Caption, UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[i]);
                    }
                    Session.Add("UserInfo", sessionData);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("main");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log
                return RedirectToAction("index.mon");
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is very simple, **putting Dataset values into `userModel`**. But what bothers me is that *the Dataset has more items than the model has.*

**I don't know how to match the data and set values when two objects are not the same**.

should I use loop? or is there any **casting** object that helps **mapping** the data?
please! .NET framework must have something useful! 
And if you have more time to spare, do you know the better practice to fetch the data in MVC4?

Using dataset looks old-fashioned to me. but I don't want to any third party framework. just achieve these in pure .NET framework

Comment: Did you try http://automapper.org/ ?

Comment: why you didn't use linq? Do you have your own membership provider? is it implemented completely?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi I don't know much about linq. I'm new to .NET. that's why I couldn't use it :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like Fluent NHibernate or Entity Framework, this is exactly what they're designed for - mapping relational data from a database to c# objects.

My preference is fluent nhibernate, you can install it via nuget and check out the getting started guide at https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started

**UPDATE:** Pure .NET approach

If you don't want to use any external libraries you could write a simple static method for mapping your data to an object like this:

```
protected static userModel GetUserFromReader(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var user = new userModel
    {
        userNo = reader["userNo"],
        userCode = reader["userCode"],
        userName = reader["userName"]
    };

    return user;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but I don't want to set up anything besides .NET Framework. I just do this purely with .NET

Answer (score 0):

- To understand **how to use Dataset in view** look at [Using DataSet
  As Data Model in asp.net MVC 4 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451028/using-dataset-as-data-model-in-asp-net-mvc-4-project)
- And to understand how to **Convert**, look at [How to return a DataSet to
  a View.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982886/how-to-return-a-dataset-to-a-view)