# displaying data set in view from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please understand I am new to asp.net. I created a data structure utilizing QueriesTableAdapeter and now I would like to update my view and controller so I may be able to display the data.

My controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace KCware.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AxiomDS()
    {
        //return AxiomDS();
        return View();

    }

}
```

}

My view thus far:

```
@model IEnumerable<KCware.Models.DataSet1>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @(item);

}
```

Here is the structure of my project:

[image]

Comment: Don't use DataSets in your view. You need to create a model to represent you data and pass a collection of the model to the view. And have you even tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to follow the sample project on [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) would be a good start for you including the approach that you are looking for as shown below:

*The Student\Index.cshtml view displays this list in a table:*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Update:**

If you are looking for an approach for retrieving data as from a Dataset, you might have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982886/how-to-return-a-dataset-to-a-view) page.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes I followed this sample but my approach is a bit different creating the data-structure the way I did.

Comment: @rfguy Please have a look at my Update.